# Can you put li elements inside a div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, list, menu

Ok, so I have looked around w3c and blogs and have not found an argument as to why I cannot do the following html:

```
<ul>
    <div><li>1</li></div>
    <div><li>2</li></div>
    <div><li>3</li></div>
</ul>
```

I know intuitively this doesn't look right but I can't find a reference that says you can't do it.

Comment: You can add classes to li element, so why you need div's?

Comment: The problem originally started when I needed to add a scroll bar to a bootstrap menu. The sub-menus don't pop out of the menu. I followed this post https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/ as a guide but it begged the question. I'm just looking for some reference material that says you can't do this because it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search for "HTML Validator" you can quickly run some code through one to see if it is valid or not. Div tags aren't valid as first level child elements of a ul tag. Whatever you are trying to achieve can be accomplished by styling the li tags with CSS.

Comment: So I did upload a html page and it did give an error and is pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

No. This is invalid HTML.

> Permittend content: zero or more `<li>` elements, eventually mixed with
>   `<ol>` and `<ul>` elements.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

Comment: This still doesn't say I can't do it. And from what I have seen on the w3c documentation "The  DIV and SPAN elements, in conjunction with the id and  class attributes, offer a generic mechanism for adding structure to documents. These elements define content to be inline (SPAN) or block-level (DIV) but impose no other presentational idioms on the content. Thus, authors may use these elements in conjunction with style sheets" (source:http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#edf-DIV ), DIV's are just dividers in your HTML DOM.