# why does <li> element under <div> renders different from <li> element under <ul>?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

i want to temporarily place a **li** element under a **div**
but i have noticed that the element renders differently even when the **div** parent  is styled exactly as the original **ul** parent.
any reason for this behaviour?
any way to emulate the **ul** tag with a **div** tag?

```js
function copy(){
  var ul = document.getElementById ('real-ul');
  var div = document.getElementById('emulate-ul');
  var cStyle = (window.getComputedStyle) ? window.getComputedStyle(ul, null) : ul.currentStyle;
  for(var property in cStyle){
   div.style[property] = cStyle[property];
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="emulate-ul">
    <li>ITEM li under a div</li>
  </div>
  <ul id="real-ul">
    <li>ITEM li under a ul</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button onclick="copy()">
copy all computed styles
</button>
```

Comment: Because it's invalid HTML? Why would you do that?

Comment: If all you want is the symbol, why not use &bull;

Comment: i need to temporarily move an existing element to another div.

Answer (score 0):

The `ul` element has a few default css props in most browsers, I think this is an accuarate list:

```
ul { 
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

You can see that the `margin` before and after and the `padding-start` are causing the difference here. I suppose you could add them to your bounding `div` to recreate the styling of a `ul`.

Comment: even when all these props are applied to the div element the li element still renders differently

Comment: Yea it's not quite the same, and it'll be tough to fake because as other's have noted, this isn't valid HTML [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921734/can-you-put-li-elements-inside-a-div). You could have an empty `ul` in the `div` and move the element in there though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't put `<li>` elements inside `<div>` without `<ul>` This is how you could put it:

```
<div>
  <div id="emulate-ul">
    <ul>
     <li>ITEM li under a div</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="some-id">
   <ul id="real-ul">
     <li>ITEM li under a ul</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```